# Trying to get div blocks left to right but they are stuck on the left

Tags: css, html

I'm attempting to get the blog posts for this student staff to go left to right and auto wrap to the next line.  The problem is that the `div` blocks will only stay to the left side.  Is there something I'm missing in the CSS?

```
.page_container {
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-height: 250px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
}

.staff_container {
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
```

[Weber State PRSSA Staff Page here](http://www.weberstateprssa.com/staff-members/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

[image]

I added these styles:

```
.post {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

.staff_container {
    width: 100%;
}
```